# Issue testing user-defined exception when imported from module into __init__.py

Tags: python, exception

I am attempting to write a large module split into multiple files while keeping it unified in a single logical module, as described in [Ch. 10 of the Python Cookbook](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000393/ch10.html#_problem_172)

However, in my unit test, I'm receiving an unexpected error when testing for an exception.  When I am attempting to force an exception, I expect the exception `package.MyExceptionError` to be raised.  However, my test is failing, because I am getting the exception `package.module.MyExceptionError`.  On the other hand, when I call a function from a module that has been imported via `__init__.py`, I'm able to call it as `package.my_function()` as expected.

I've looked through the code for several PyPi modules that are similarly laid-out, but I'm not able to determine what I'm doing incorrectly, or am I misunderstanding how this should work?

Below is a dummy package, which includes the minimum code necessary to replicate the issue.

My file structure is:

```
Spam/
    spam/
        __init__.py
        eggs.py

    test/
        test_eggs.py
```

Here are the contents of `spam/eggs.py`:

```
class EggError(Exception):
    pass



def egg(b=True):

    if b == True:
        return 0

    else:
        raise EggError('Spam!')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

Here are the contents of `spam/__init__.py`:

```
from .egg import egg
from .egg import EggError

__all__ = ['egg', 'EggError', ]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

Here are the contents of `test/test_spam.py`:

```
import unittest
import spam


class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_egg(self):
        self.assertEquals(spam.egg(), 0)

    def test_EggError(self):
        self.assertRaises(spam.EggError, spam.egg(False))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

These are the results I get when I run the test:

```
Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ... done.

======================================================================
ERROR: test_EggError (test.test_spam.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "K:\Scripting\Python\err_test\test\test_spam.py", line 11, in test_EggError
    self.assertRaises(spam.EggError, spam.egg(False))
  File "K:\Scripting\Python\err_test\spam\eggs.py", line 12, in egg
    raise EggError('Spam!')
spam.eggs.EggError: Spam!

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.415s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: You could just define EggError in \_\_init\_\_.py rather than eggs.py.

Comment: I thought of that and will do it if I need to, but it breaks the logic of grouping things functionally into modules, then pulling them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `spam.egg()` before `assertRaises()` has a chance to catch the exception.  You should write that test as follows:

```
self.assertRaises(spam.EggError, spam.egg, False)
```

`assertRaises()` will call `spam.egg()` for you.

If you find this hard to read, you can use the context manager style instead:

```
with self.assertRaises(spam.EggError):
    spam.egg(False)
```

Comment: Well duh! That makes sense. In other words, I'm generating the error myself outside of a `try ... except` block, so _of course_ it's going to throw an error.  Thanks for being helpful enough to point out the obvious. :-D